# I get the AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute "name_of_attribute"

Tags: python, list, dictionary

**Updated**

I have seen this posted very frequently, and I have tried to apply the solutions offered, but they don't work because I don't quite understand python.

I am working with AnnData objects for numerous samples, and I am trying to streamline the analysis

I am familiar with lists from experience in R, so I started with:

```
for sample in samples:
adata_atac_list[sample] = sc.read_10x_mtx(
    os.path.join(
        _10xfilesPath+sample+"/filtered_feature_bc_matrix/"),
    var_names='gene_symbols',
    cache=True,
    gex_only=False)
```

I also tried to keep the sample names associated with the objects because I prefer it that way.

The next step is to filter the data for a specific feature type:

```
def limit_features(atac_list:list)-> list:
    temp = atac_list.var['feature_types']
    return atac_list[:,temp=="Peaks"]
```

The function works when I test it over a single entry in the dictionary:

```
atac_adata_list['sample_A_1'].var[0:2]
```

|  | gene_ids | feature_types: |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chr01:8327-9319 | Chr01:8327-9319 | Peaks |
| Chr01:16469-17362 | Chr01:16469-17362 | Peaks |

But over the entire dictionary I get the the error:

```
atac_adata_list = list(map(limit_features, atac_adata_list))
```

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'var'

(I used the method from [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/apply-function-to-each-element-of-a-list-python/) link to apply my function.)

From what I've read, I think it means that my function is interpreting my sample names as strings instead of using them to apply the function to each element of the list. (The conversations had a lot of python jargon.) One solution I saw relied on `ast`:

```
import ast
atac_adata_list = list(map(limit_features, ast.literal_eval(atac_adata_list)))
```

> ValueError: malformed node or string: {'sample_A_1': AnnData object with n_obs × n_vars = 1552 × 80487
> var: 'gene_ids', 'feature_types', 'sample_A_1': AnnData object with n_obs × n_vars = 2647 × 76427...

So I guess using `ast.literal_eval()` wasn't quite what I should have implemented either.

I am new to python, and while I would be happy with a quick solve to my problem, I would also appreciate any explanation the explains the back-end of why this fails. I saw some recommendations to use `dict` rather than `list` but I have the same errors in that case also.

*I am sorry if my question isn't perfectly formatted. I tried my best.*

***UPDATE

I tried slothtrop's suggestion to use `.values()`:

```
adata_atac_dict2 = dict(map(limit_features, adata_atac_dict.values()))
```

But his prediction that more was wrong was correct:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) Cell In[166], line 1
> ----> 1 adata_atac_dict2 = dict(map(limit_features, adata_atac_dict.values()))
>
> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1552; 2
> is required
> It must still be related to mapping/dictionary because

```
adata_atac_dict2 = limit_features(adata_atac_dict['sample_A_1'])
```

produces the desired output

Comment: From the error, it seems like you are in fact already using a `dict` rather than a `list`. When you do `map(some_func, some_dict)`, the function is applied to each *key* in the dict, not to each *value*, and this would correspond exactly to the observed *"interpreting my sample names as strings"*. The immediate fix for that would be `map(some_func, some_dict.values())`. But it looks like there are further problems here, e.g. your `map` would apply to each value individually, but `limit_features` appears as if it's designed to take a list rather than an individual AnnData object.

Comment: btw, "list" doesn't really mean the same thing in Python as in R. An R list is roughly like a Python dict; a Python list is roughly like an R vector.

Comment: @slothrop I'm reminded of so many things: Pulp Fiction's "Royale with Cheese"; Steve Martin's "Boy, those French, they have a different word for everything!"

Comment: When you use `dict(x)` to build a dictionary from an iterable `x`, that iterable has to yield **pairs** of values (which become the key:value pairs in the resulting dictionary). So you can't use that with the result of `map(limit_features, adata_atac_dict.values()))`, because `limit_features` doesn't return pairs. Maybe you want something like `adata_atac_dict2 = {k: limit_features(v) for k, v in adata_atac_dict.items()}` ?

Comment: btw I think the type annotations of `limit_features` are wrong: the input should be an `AnnData` object, not a `list`? But those are just hints for typechecking tools in Python, so won't cause your code to fail.

Comment: Do you mean where I declare`limit_features` function, I should use `def limit_features(atac_list:ad)->ad:` or `def limit_features(atac_list:AnnData)->AnnData:` instead? I tried that, but it didn't solve the issue. The demos for working with AnnData are a bit bare bones.

Comment: Yes, that change makes sense, but no, it won't affect the issue: as I say, type annotations in Python are just hints for the reader and the development tools.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your second to last response, but, yes, I think that solved it! But I don't know how. What are the k, v and items? I can search for items() I think I think but not sure where to read up on the k and v stuff. Thank you btw, you're immensely helpful. Also, I can't select your comment as answering my question? Can you make it an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: Done, hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question and the clarification in the comments, the situation is that:

- you have a dictionary `adata_atac_dict` where the keys are strings (representing sample names), and the values are `AnnData` objects.
- the function `limit_features` takes a single `AnnData` object as input, and returns an `AnnData` object as output (transformed according to your specific requirements)
- you want to get an output which contains the result of applying `limit_features` to each of the `AnnData` objects in `adata_atac_dict`, with each of the resulting objects still associated with the sample name.

This can be done most concisely using a [dictionary comprehension](https://peps.python.org/pep-0274/) in Python:

```
adata_atac_dict2 = {k: limit_features(v) for k, v in adata_atac_dict.items()}
```

In this statement, `.items()` yields each key (`k`) - value (`v`) pair from the original `adata_atac_dict`. We construct a new dictionary where each key is the original `k` but each value is `limit_features(v)` instead of the original `v`.

(Note, using `k` and `v` here is a common convention, but you could use any name of your choice. For example:

```
adata_atac_dict2 = {sample_name: limit_features(sample_data) for sample_name, sample_data in adata_atac_dict.items()}
```

does the same thing, and makes the meaning of the data clearer for the reader at the expense of a bit of verbosity).

---

As a side note, it looks like the type hints are wrong on your original `limit_features`. They should be:

```
def limit_features(atac_list: AnnData) -> AnnData:
```

Since Python type annotations are not checked at runtime – they're just hints for the reader and for IDEs and type-checking tools – this isn't causing your code to behave incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you so much. This explanation helped a lot to detangle the mess. It also helped me understand the function declaration better: I didn't know about type hints and just copied what I saw from other examples. I got an error that AnnData wasn't declared, which made sense once I read more about how to use type hints. I only had to add `from anndata import AnnData` to circumvent that, and reading more about Dict Comprehensions allowed me to use direct substitution functions on my data (rather than writing return function myself for everything.)